# Does 3G has to start and stop with every transmission? (energy overhead)

Tags: nexus-4, 3g, cellular-radio

Does anyone know what has to happen for 3G to send some data (when 3G is on in Android settings, using Nexus 4)?
Does it has to initialize somehow at the beginning or to go back to some stable mode in the end of every transmission?
If yes, would length of that tail or head overhead depend on size of transmitted file/data?

Comment: This question is borderline off-topic, since cell radio chips that are baked into most phones are for the most part OS-agnostic. Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: what *head* or *tail* are you referring to? Does not make sense. As @chakh stated, care to pin-point specifically what is the problem at hand?